# ClientIDMode How to hide ID in Html Source code generated in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use .net 4 and c#.

I have a asp.net Page wit an HyperLink.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="uxLink" ClientIDMode ="Static" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

In my code behind I use the HyperLink `ID="uxLink"` to change some properties.

In my browser the code generate is:

```
<a id="uxLink" href="/blog/5/test.aspx">Test link</a>
```

I would need omit the  id from the source code generated in the browser so it should look:

```
<a href="/blog/5/test.aspx">Test link</a>
```

I tried to play with ClientIdMode but with no succe... Any idea how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change the ID propriety for the control in code behind before rendering the page to `NULL`.

in my example:

```
myLink.ID = null;
```

This would generate no ID at the Browser resulting in:

```
<a href="/blog/5/test.aspx">Test link</a>
```

I find this useful trick on this website:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-id

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `ClientIDMode ="Static"`, the framework will generate a "big unique" ID for the element, but still, there will be an ID.

Having an ID is fundamental if you want to handle the elements in client-side script. The IDs should not be removed.

If you don't want them, just don't use ASP.NET components, use the `<a>` tag itself.

**Update**

By the way, supposedly there's a way to do what you want in ASP.NET 4. It's described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/208323/Disable-ClientID-for-any-control-on-ASP-NET-Page?display=Print

I haven't tried it, I'm just pointing you into a direction. You should be aware of the implications of not having a ClientID, though. Specially for Postback controls. Read the article.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I also find a very simple solution (posted here), tell me what do you think thanks

Comment: I had a look to the article, yes is really interested. Practically at the moment I'm using directly the propriety ID for the control so I can precisely disable the ID without adding overhead to my application with adapters.